# Iterators for the copy-on-write collections

Tags: java

An abstract from **JCIP**

> Iterators for the copy-on-write collections retain a reference to the
>   backing array that was **current at the start of iteration**, and since
>   **this will never change**, they need to synchronize only briefly to
>   ensure visibility of the array contents.
>
> The iterators returned by the copy-on-write collections do not throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException and **return the elements exactly as
>   they were at the time the iterator was created, regardless of
>   subsequent modifications**

Looking at the source code at [#CopyOnWriteArrayList.iterator()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html#iterator())

```
956         public Iterator<E> iterator() {
957              return new COWIterator<E>(getArray(), 0); // call to private constructor
958         }

993         private final Object[] snapshot;

994 
995         private int cursor;
996 
997         private COWIterator(Object[] elements, int initialCursor) {
998             cursor = initialCursor;
999             snapshot = elements;  
1000        }
```

You see that the `snapshot` points to the array returned by `getArray()` and since the array reference returned is volatile, any change on the reference variable is guaranteed to be reflected. (*Making the array reference volatile doesn't makes the elements at each index location volatile*)

where the change on the array is done inside-

```
386     public E More ...set(int index, E element) {
387         final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
388         lock.lock();
389         try {
390             Object[] elements = getArray();
391             E oldValue = get(elements, index);
392 
393             if (oldValue != element) {
394                 int len = elements.length;
395                 Object[] newElements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, len);
396                 newElements[index] = element;
397                 setArray(newElements);
398             } else {
399                 // Not quite a no-op; ensures volatile write semantics
400                 setArray(elements);
401             }
402             return oldValue;
403         } finally {
404             lock.unlock();
405         }
406     }
```

i.e  `setArray(newElements);` as seen in the method.

where **getArray()**

```
92      final Object[] More ...getArray() {
93          return array;
94      }
```

& **setArray(...)**

```
final void More ...setArray(Object[] a) {
100         array = a;
101     }
```

are operations on this volatile array

```
private volatile transient Object[] array;
```

Clearly, the iterator is returning the array which (if) has been modified, and not the one created at the start of the iteration process.

So, what does the author mean-

> return the elements exactly as they were at the time the **iterator was
>   created**, regardless of subsequent modifications.

Comment: I looked at the code you posted here and clearly, the iterator is returning an array that's never modified.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: But concurrently other threads can clearly modified it through `set(int index, E element).`

Comment: *"Clearly, the iterator is returning the array"* Ehh, nooo. "Clearly", the iterator is *using* the array obtained at the time the iterator was *created*. Any subsequent modification of the list will create a *new* array, so the iterator will not see those changes.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari I see no evidence of that, instead I see modification of a new array which is subsequently assigned as the "current" array. Once assigned, it never changes.

Comment: @Andreas: I never said it doesn't creates a new array on every mutation. But the reference remains the same. `setArray(newElements);`

Comment: Can you describe in your own words what the `setArray` method does?

Comment: What do you mean "the reference remains the same"? `setArray(Object[] a) { array = a; }` *updates* the reference. How can you say it "remains the same", when you yourself just showed the code that changes it?

Comment: The new array is assigned to the same reference as seen clearly in `array = a;` in `setArray`

Comment: You just need a basic lesson on the semantics of Java's variables and references. "Assigned to the same reference" is a meaningless  statement because a reference is just a value. A reference is assigned to a variable, not the other way.

Comment: Yes, so the `array` reference of the list is *changed*! It now points to a *different* array. However, the `snapshot` reference in the `COWIterator` is *unchanged*, and still points to the old array.

Comment: @Andreas: Yes, that's exactly the answer.

Comment: Same answer [@AR.3 already gave you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39848135/5221149) 10+ minutes ago: *assigning its reference to the `array` field will **keep the `snapshot` of the iterator pointing to the same old reference***

Comment: @Andreas: Not a native English speaker, sometimes it happens. I accept it's my fault.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I deeply apologize.

Comment: I didn't notice any offense on your part. Apologies are not due.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> since the array returned is volatile, any change on the reference variable is guaranteed to be reflected.

This has nothing to do with `volatile` semantics. The reference to the array is created when the `COWIterator` constructor is called (when the iterator is created). Creating a new copy of the array and assigning its reference to the `array` field will keep the `snapshot` of the iterator pointing to the same old reference.

Comment: That's what I have written-  the snapshot points to the array returned by getArray()

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari Yes but `setArray` changes the reference to a completely different array. You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari Exactly! The array *at the time* `getArray()` is called. Subsequent calls to `getArray()` may return a different array, but `getArray()` is never called again by the `Iterator` *during* the iteration.

Comment: See my comment above on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you instanciate a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, now `elements` is referencing an array:

elements -> [0, 1, 2]

Now you create a `COWIterator`, `snapshot` is referencing the same array:

elements -> [0, 1, 2] <- snapshot

Now you add a new element to the `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, a **new** array is created and the reference is updated to the new array:

snapshot -> [0, 1, 2]

elements -> [0, 1, 3]

So, `snapshot` still points to the initial array !

Comment: It was a language barrier problem for me. I completely misinterpreted the statement.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you've pasted here has these lines (not copied a few lines in between) :
    Object[] elements = getArray();
    Object[] newElements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, len);
    newElements[index] = element;

Line 1 refers to the existing array that backs this collection. If you try to get an iterator before the collection is updated, then this is the array (referred to as snapshot)  iterator gets.

Line 2 is a new array being created by copying (hence the COW) and then new item being added to it as seen in line 3.

This newElements array is then assigned to volatile array reference. Iterator is already referring to older snapshot array, so it doesn't even know about the array being updated.

Hope that explains.